# why there is a gap space between DIV inline block boxes?

Tags: html, css

when I use display = inline-block to my div, there is a gap between these 2 boxes. can anyone tell me why it is like this, and how can I remove the gap?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.first {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
}
.second {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

Comment: The easiest fix would be to delete the line break between the two `<div>`s

Answer (score 3):

Use `float: left;`

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.first {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block; float:left
}
.second {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;float:left
}
```

Answer (score 2):

set `font-size: 0` for parent element.

```
.parent-element {  /* apply to the parent element */
  font-size: 0;
}

.first, .second {
     font-size: 13px; /* default value, change as per your need */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your html like blow

other way add Comment like blow

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.first {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
}
.second {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="first"></div><div class="second"></div>

<div class="first"></div><!--
--><div class="second"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> @Chao Wang for removing that gap you have to use left float in bot the
>   div

```
<style type="text/css">
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.first {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}
.second {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  display: inline-block;
  float:left;
}

</style>
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
```

It will resolve your problem (y)

Answer (score 0):

The "inline-block" elements has this space because of font size of the parent.
[Here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) you can find more details and ways how to remove the space. One of the easiest is this to add a div parent with font-size=0:

```
<div style="font-size: 0;">
<div class="first"></div>
<div class="second"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happen beacause it use line height

```css
.inline-parent{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  line-height:0;
  font-size:0;
}
.inline1{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  background:#333;
  line-height:1;
  font-size:15px;
}
.inline2{
  display:inline-block;
  width:50%;
  background:#999;
  line-height:1;
  font-size:15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-parent">
<div class="inline1">
text text
</div>
<div class="inline2">
text text
</div>
</div>
```

It is all because of `line-height` and `font-size`